# array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php, arrays, push

I have the following php code:

```
<?php

class Session {

    public function __construct() {
        if (!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
        if (!is_array($_SESSION['messages'])) {
            $_SESSION['messages'] = [];
        }
        echo is_array($_SESSION['messages']);
    }

    public function AddMessage($msg="") {
        array_push($_SESSION['messages'], $msg);
    }

    public function GetMessages() {
        $messages = $_SESSION['messages'];
        unset($_SESSION['messages']);
        return $messages;
    }

}

$session = new Session();

?>
```

And the output of $session->AddMessage('message') is:

```
1 
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ...\Session.php on line 16
```

so is_array clearly says that $_SESSION['messages'] IS an array.
What am I missing?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error, this is usually caused by missing information in the question. Are you calling the `$session->AddMessage('message')` immediately after `$session = new Session()`?

Comment: Did you happen to call `GetMessages()` before `AddMessage()`?

Comment: **Note**: OP has edited the http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34931400/1

Comment: I made an edit. It's OK now.

Comment: Then close/delete it...

Comment: @user3210615 No problem, actually you shouldn't update answer in your question. So that any future visitors might find the right answer from the answer section. not in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) is a function, so it should be:

```
    if (!session_id()) { //Not just session_id
        session_start();
    }
```

If you would have turned on error reporting it might have thrown:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant session_id - assumed 'session_id'

**Note**: OP has edited the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34931400/1)